# Long Click on a list view and a delete dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using `onlongitemclick` and can produce a dialog that comes up to confirm a delete, but I cannot get the `listitem` position or text.

Edit: I cannot get the selectedValue string value inside of the public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) function.

`lv` is my `listview` object

```
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
    {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
             ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
              final String selectedValue = (String) list1.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new  AlertDialog.Builder(RecipeList.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                alertDialog.setMessage(selectedValue);     
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                obj Recipe = new obj(selectedValue, RecipeList.this);

                                Recipe.remove(<I need the listview item to create the object and then delete some listing in the DB, seletecValue should do this, but it does not>)
                                Intent intent2 = new Intent(RecipeList.this, RecipeList.class); //go to recipe list
                                startActivity(intent2);

                   } }); 
                   alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Keep", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          // alertDialog.dismiss();
                   } }); 

                   alertDialog.show();
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this:

final String selectedValue = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

I think arg0, arg1 etc. are bad names, so change them to something meaningful as in the documentation.

Comment: When I debug and get set the final selectedValue variable I get what I expect. But then when I click the delete button and watch selectedValue while it is in the public void onClick for the delete button I do not get any value for selected Value

Answer (score 2):

`arg1` is your view, you should be able to get the text from the view.

`arg2` is the position.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

Comment: When I debug and get set the final selectedValue variable I get what I expect. But then when I click the delete button and watch selectedValue while it is in the public void onClick for the delete button I do not get any value for selected Value